# How can I tell whether an image is being served by Nginx or the Rails app?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, nginx

I'm new to programming and trying to learn more about a particular website I've been helping maintain. How can I tell whether an image is being served up by Nginx or the Rails asset pipeline? Some of the images are loading properly, while others are not (on production only), which is why I suspect the images are being processed differently.

Answer (score 1):

It is most likely your web server, unless your rails app is on port 80. You should try `grepping` your access log for any `GETS` to your image.

For example :

`grep pony.jpg /var/log/httpd/access_log`.

This will also work for grepping your error_log for any images that may 404. 
Hope this helps.